# Is there a way to properly format an Ubuntu font?

Tags: python, fonts, programming, python3

I'm trying to distribute Ubuntu Mono Regular with a Media Player I'm developing: https://github.com/ki4jgt/SIMP

It is my understanding that a font is defined like in line 27

```
uMono = pyglet.font.load("Ubuntu Mono")
```

and then referenced in line 168 as:

```
pyglet.text.Label(entry, font_name = uMono, font_size = 12, x = 10, y = a, anchor_x = "left", anchor_y = "top").draw()
```

Python/Pyglet complains when uMono is used because the font is incompatible with Pyglet. The documentation says that the font needs to be properly formatted to be read. Are there any Ubuntu tools which can modify the font to comply with standards?